# Pi OS Lite on Pi Zero WH Crashes with "undefined instruction" using apt upgrade

Tags: crash

I have tried three C10 SD cards on this device, flashing Pi OS, Pi OS lite and Raspbian Buster and all of these exhibit the same thing:
An undefined instruction exception when running "apt upgrade" - Because the kernel panic handler does not flush syslog I could only capture it in a photo and it's not great.

So, do I need to find even better cards (my Pi 3B can run on practically anything)? Is this specific board fubar or do I need some other esoteric OS to run this?

I've done a lot of googling about it and can't find anything on point. I know I can look for libraries or code that use the Arm 7 instruction set, but then what?

[image: Crash]

Comment: this error only occurs when running `apt update`? or does it occur with any `apt` command, e.g. `apt list --installed` - what about `apt-get update` - does that fail similarly?

Comment: Welcome. I don't think "undefined instruction" has the specificity associated with "illegal instruction"; the issue here isn't the wrong ISA -- it would never have gotten far enough to produce that stack trace.  Also notice the process referred to is `http`, for what that is worth.  Are you sure using `apt` is really the only thing that triggers this?

Comment: Did a bit of searching around and while the ultimate cause *could* be an illegal instruction, it is not necessarily: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/b/System-Level-Architecture/The-System-Level-Programmers--Model/Exceptions/Undefined-Instruction-exception ... https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0471/m/handling-processor-exceptions/undefined-instruction-handlers

Comment: Is this resolved? It looks like something's been plaguing the OP for a while but in a week, they haven't filled in any of the blanks as requested by the community. 
Assuming this is a virgin OS install, on a virgin board, my money is on a hardware fault. 
Suggest flashing a fresh OS onto one of your known working SD cards (after backing it up of course.) That would point the finger at the board.
If you've resolved it, there's kudos available for answering your own question...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with my pi zero w and raspbian bullseye and I have tried to increase the cpu voltage and frequency in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
over_voltage=4
arm_freq=1000
```

After setting and rebooting, with the command `vcgencmd measure_volts` I found the voltage has been modified to 1.4000V, then I ran `apt upgrade` again and it just worked fine without any issue.